# Zsh: append an element a dynamically-named associative array

Tags: zsh

I have several associative arrays,

```sh
typeset -A first
typeset -A second
# …
```

and want to add an element (e.g. `[a]=b`) to one of them, but cannot find the right syntax. Started at

```sh
if something; then
  arr=first
else
  arr=second
fi

$arr[a]+=b # bad
$arr+=([a]=b) # bad
```

and have tried many mixes of quotation marks, braces, various subscripts and parameter expansion flags, `arr=$first`/`arr=$second`, etc. Everything I've tried is an error. Can it be done?

Comment: Two suggestions : 1. Edit the first line to say "I have two **associative** arrays." ; 2. Include a concrete example of these associative arrays.

Comment: Added "associative" to the first sentence to match the question. The examples I've given work and are equivalent to any other particular array names/keys/values, so leaving them as they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is ideal but it should get the job done.

```
export "${arr}[a]"=b
```

Comment: It does indeed!  Is your hesitation because of having to think about scope, or something more?

Comment: export implies global, you could also try `typeset -x`

Comment: Note that `export "${arr}[$key]=$value"` doesn't work if `$key` contains `]`s,`(`s, `)`s or backslashes or is `*`, `@` or the empty string. `eval $arr'[$key]=$value'` should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

This should also work in many cases:

```
eval "${arr}[a]=b"
```

`eval` has a bad reputation (often deservedly so), but with simple substitutions like those being used here, it should be fine.

Comment: Or `eval $arr'[$key]=$value'` for arbitrary keys and values.